# how do I display the image in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I am retrieving image bytes from mysql database through the following Servlet method:

and then display the image bytes in a jsp page.

> Please tell me how do I use the img tag in my jsp page.

```
    public byte[] getProfilePicture( int id ) {

    byte[] bytes = null;

    try {

        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        pst = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT profile_picture FROM users WHERE id = '"+id+"' ");
        resultSet = pst.executeQuery();

        while( resultSet.next() ) {

            bytes = resultSet.getBytes("profile_picture");

        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bytes;

}
```

> Thanks, I am waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make it a resource within your web App that can be accessed using JSP/Servlet.

**Example 1 Fixed Loaction:**

Servlet Location: http://www.cvss.online/captcha

JSP Code:

```
<div class="six columns">
     <label>Captcha image</label>
     <img src="captcha"> 
</div>
```

**Example 2 Dynamic Location by ID:**

Each image has a unique ID

```
    ...
    int imgId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("imgId"));
    // Your Logic
    ...
```

**Your Example:**

Within your resultSet.next() block add:

```
byte imageArray[] = rs.getBytes(1);
response.setContentType("image/type"); //type png jif etc
outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(imageArray);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Cheers